# Wrapping library functions to retry on 500 errors not working properly

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-decorators

I'm trying to wrap all the functions in an instance of a library to retry on 500 errors (wrapping in order to avoid forcing team members to specially add retry code on each function). I've done similar stuff before, but for BigQuery, I'm having no luck. Here's my code:

```
def bq_methods_retry(func):
    num_retries = 5
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*a, **kw):
        sleep_interval = 2
        for i in xrange(num_retries):
            try:
                return func(*a, **kw)
            except apiclient.errors.HttpError, e:
                if e.resp.status == 500 and i < num_retries-1:
                    logger.info("got a 500. retrying.")
                    time.sleep(sleep_interval)
                    sleep_interval = min(2*sleep_interval, 60)
                else:
                    logger.info('failed with unexpected apiclient error:')
                    raise e
            except:
                logger.info('failed with unexpected error:')
                raise
    return wrapper


def decorate_all_bq_methods(instance, decorator):
    for k, f in instance.__dict__.items():
        if inspect.ismethod(f):
            name = f.func_name
            setattr(instance, k, decorator(f))
    return instance

...
service = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
#make all the methods in the service retry when appropriate
service = decorate_all_bq_methods(service, bq_methods_retry)
jobs = decorate_all_bq_methods(service.jobs(), bq_methods_retry)
```

Then, when I run something like:

```
jobs.query(projectId=some_id, body=some_query).execute()
```

500 Errors are never caught by bq_methods_retry, but pass along to the rest of the program.

Any ideas? I'm also open to a better retry solution.

Answer (score 2):

The BigQuery client that the bq command line tool uses does something similar by wrapping the HTTP object. It doesn't do a retry, but it does translate exceptions, so you could likely use the same type of hook.

Note that you may want to be careful about retrying certain types of operations; for example, if you retry a job insert that appends data, if it hit a network error returning the response, the original request might actually succeed, so you'll be inserting the same data twice. To avoid this, you can pass in your own job id, which should prevent it from being run twice (since the job will already exist the second time).

Check out the code [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/source/browse/bq/bigquery_client.py?r=30df4638ff2ddb01d3f495af5c131ed3c2cfbd04#140).

Comment: But I'm not executing on the HTTP object. Can you explain more about how/why this would work?

I'm already supplying my own job-ids for all inserts and table-creations for the exact reason you mentioned, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: when you build the service object, you pass it an HTP object that will be used for subsequent calls to bigquery. So if you wrap that http object with something that will do retries, it should apply to any subsequent bigquery calls that you make.